# Assume $x \geq 1$ and deduce $x^{1/n} \geq 1$

Tags: inequality

What I've done:

Assume$$x^{1/n}<1$$
$$(x^{1/n})^n<1^{n}$$
$$x<1$$
So we have a contradiction. Is this sufficient?

Comment: Yes, it is sufficient.

Comment: Should be $(x^{1/n})^n<1^n$ on the second line. What is your initial knowledge of the function $x\mapsto x^{1/n}$ ? If you know it's increasing, then there is no need for contradiction.

Comment: This is not really a contradiction proof, but a proof of the contrapositive statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is valid.

You could have a direct proof as well

Note that the function $f(x)= x^{1/n}$ is strictly increasing on $(0,\infty)$ since its derivative is positive.

Therefore, 
$$ x>1\implies x^{1/n}>1^{1/n}=1$$

Comment: The question literally says "Assume that $x\geq 1$ and deduce that $x^{1/n}\geq 1$ so I think there needs to be a bit more

Comment: @m.bazza Thanks for your comment. I added a line to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

$x\ge1\implies\ln x\ge0\implies\dfrac1n\ln x\ge0\implies\ln x^{\frac1n}\ge0\implies x^{\frac1n}\ge e^0=1$

Answer (score 0):

$$x^{1/n}-1=\frac{x-1}{x^{(n-1)/n}+\cdots+x^{1/n}+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes your proof is valid, indeed since $f(x)=x^\frac1n$ for $x\ge 1$ is an increasing function we have

$$x\ge 1 \iff x^{1/n}\ge 1$$